# How can I remember state after back navigation?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen for listings. When a listing is tapped on I navigate to the comments screen and fetch the comments using the permalink of the listing. When pressing back and clicking on the same listing again, it looks like the state is cleared so I have to fetch the same data. I don't want to fetch the same data if the permalink hasn't changed.

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = NavRoutes.AUTH.name) {
        fun navToComments(url: String, permalink: String) {
            navController.navigate("${NavRoutes.COMMENTS.name}?url=$url&permalink=$permalink")
        }
        composable(
            route = "${NavRoutes.COMMENTS.name}?url={url}&permalink={permalink}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("url") {
                type = NavType.StringType
            }, navArgument("permalink") {
                type = NavType.StringType
            })
        ) { navBackStackEntry ->
            val url = navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getString("url")
            val permalink = navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getString("permalink")
            CommentsScreen(url ?: "", permalink ?: "")
        }
        ...
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class CommentsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val authRepository: RedditAuthRepositoryImp,
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState =
        MutableStateFlow(
            CommentsUiState(
                comments = listOf<CommentModel>(),
                expandedComments = setOf<String>(),
                originalPost = null,
                permalink = ""              
            )
        )
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    fun updatePermalink(permalink: String) {
        _uiState.update { currentState -> currentState.copy(permalink = permalink) }
    }

    fun getComments(url: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val commentsResponse: List<CommentsModel> = authRepository.getComments(url)
            val originalPost: CommentModel = commentsResponse[0].data.children[0]
            val comments: List<CommentModel> =
                (commentsResponse[1].data.children)
            val expandedComments = getFlattenedComments(comments)
            _uiState.update { currentState ->
                currentState.copy(
                    expandedComments = expandedComments,
                    comments = comments,
                    originalPost = originalPost
                )
            }
        }
    }

    fun isExpanded(commentNode: CommentModel): Boolean {
        return _uiState.value.expandedComments.contains(commentNode.data.id)
    }

    ...

}
```

```
@Composable
fun CommentsScreen(
    url: String,
    permalink: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val viewModel: CommentsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val commentsUiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val originalPostData = commentsUiState.value.originalPost?.data
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        if (commentsUiState.value.permalink != permalink) {
            viewModel.getComments("$OAUTH_BASE_URL$permalink.json")
            viewModel.updatePermalink(permalink)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried hoisting the comments viewmodel outside of the navhost and passing it to the comments screen.
It worked in preventing the data from being fetched again. I see the comments and the original post data, but now none of the comments are expanded. I checked the state in the [debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eja8C.png) and the comments, expandedComments, originalPost, and permalink are all empty. I'm confused because I see the comments displayed in the emulator.

Comment: One way is to cache the data locally. If you come back the screen state is lost. The only way is store the state some where locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `hiltViewModel()`, If you are using the `hiltViewModel()` function and you navigate from **screen A** to **screen B**, the `ViewModel` for **screen A** will be destroyed. This is because the `ViewModel` is scoped to the current navigation graph, and the navigation graph for **screen A** is destroyed when you navigate to **screen B**.

If you want the `ViewModel` to persist even when you navigate away from the screen, you should use the `viewModel()` function instead. This will create a new instance of the `ViewModel` that is not scoped to the navigation graph, and the `ViewModel` will not be destroyed when you navigate away from the screen.

here is a simple exemple for how to do it:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenA(txt: String, onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,navController: NavController) {
    Column() {
        TextField(value = txt, onValueChange = { onValueChange(it) })
        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("screenB")}) {

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenB() {
    Box() {

        Text("B")
    }

}

class ViewModelA : ViewModel() {
    val txt = mutableStateOf("")
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
setContent {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val viewModelA: ViewModelA = viewModel()

        TestTheme {
            Box() {

                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "screenA") {
                    composable("screenA") {
                        ScreenA(txt = viewModelA.txt.value,
                            onValueChange = {
                                viewModelA.txt.value = it
                            }, navController = navController)
                    }
                    composable("screenB") {
                        ScreenB()
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**Note: it is better to pass value and onValueChange to screen instead of the whole viewModel.**

Comment: Thank you. I was hoisting the hiltViewModel outside the navigation graph but it didn't work. Using viewModel instead solved my issues.